# How to use bootstrap method to compute confidence interval for HMM parameters?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, hidden-markov-model

I have known how to estimate parameters in hidden Markov model by Baum-Welch algorithm. And then I was curious about how to compute the confidence interval, but I found that few articles discuss about it.
I found a [paper](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1348/000711000159240) by Visser et al. (2010), it mentioned about using bootstrap method to compute the confidence interval. It seems to be simple, but I still confused about the details.

This is the bootstrap method mentioned in the paper:
(1) Compute the maximum likelihood estimator for the HMM parameters, denote as $\hat{\lambda}$.
(2) Generate observations by HMM with MLE parameters $\hat{\lambda}$.
(3) Compute a new MLE estimator, denote as $\hat{\lambda_j}$.
(4) Repeat step 3 for several times, and obtains parameters {$\hat{\lambda_1}$, $\hat{\lambda_2}$, ..., $\hat{\lambda_K}$}.
(5) Using {$\hat{\lambda_1}$, $\hat{\lambda_2}$, ..., $\hat{\lambda_K}$} to compute the CI.

But I'm not sure how to compute the MLE estimators? Baum-Welch algorithm is suitable for this problem, but it is sensitive to the initial values and it may converge to the wrong place (local maximum). In order to obtain a better solution, I should try several initial values and use the best one.
In step 1, I think I should use several initial values to obtain the MLE estimator. But I'm not sure if it is needed in step 3? That is, consider the two pseudo-codes:

```
# step 1
lambda = BaumWelch(observations, initial_value = random())
for i = 1, 100
    tmp = BaumWelch(initial_value = random())
    if (tmp is better than lambda)
        lambda = tmp
    end if
end

# step 2
observations_new = hmm_generate_obs(lambda)

# step 3 & 4
lambda_boot = List[]
for j = 1, K
    lambda_j = BaumWelch(observations_new, initial_value = random())
    lambda_boot[j] = lambda_j
end for

# step 5
ci_lower = quantile(lambda_boot, 0.025)
ci_upper = quantile(lambda_boot, 0.975)
```

```
# step 1
lambda = BaumWelch(observations, initial_value = random())
for i = 1, 100
    tmp = BaumWelch(initial_value = random())
    if (tmp is better than lambda)
        lambda = tmp
    end if
end

# step 2
observations_new = hmm_generate_obs(lambda)

# step 3 & 4   < --------- different here
lambda_boot = List[]
for j = 1, K
    lambda_j = BaumWelch(observations_new, initial_value = random())
    for i = 1, 100
        tmp = BaumWelch(initial_value = random())
        if (tmp is better than lambda_j)
            lambda_j = tmp
        end if
    end
    lambda_boot[j] = lambda_j
end for

# step 5
ci_lower = quantile(lambda_boot, 0.025)
ci_upper = quantile(lambda_boot, 0.975)
```

which one is proper?

If I choose the first one, the CI will be quite large. For example, if the true value is 0.2 and the MLE is 0.3, the CI may be 0.1 ~ 0.7. I have not test the second one but I believe that it will be extremely slow, compared to the first one.

Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you will want to use the second piece of code. You're computing confidence intervals and want to ask "How different could my parameters have been for a different (equally valid) dataset?".

The assumption we make is that the MLE from step 1 is close enough to the ground truth such that a dataset generated from it will itself be reasonably representative of the ground truth.

If we take that to be true, then we want to compare apples to apples, and so you should compute the new bootstrap $\lambda$ in the same way as the original MLE (by trying out lots of initial conditions).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that it will take a lot of time to obtain an CI by bootstrap.